# Formatting a float to ###.## (two decimals)

Tags: delphi

Having :

```
var
Difference: DWORD // difference shows in milliseconds
// List.Items.Count can be any 0 to ######## 
[...]
sb.panels[2].Text  := FloatToStr((((List.Items.Count) / difference) / 1000));
```

I want to format the resulting text to any `###.##` (two decimals). Using `FloatToStrF` is no success (does'nt seem to work with `DWORD`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wondering if this is a problem with math rather than formatting.  Why are you dividing the number of items by 1000?  Do you mean to divide milliseconds (your Difference variable) by 1000?  Maybe this is what you want:

```
EventRate := (List.Items.Count) / (difference / 1000);  // events per second; to make it per minute, need to change 1000 to 60000
```

Of course, you'll still want to format the result.  You'll need this as a variable or class property:

```
MyFormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
```

then, you'll need to do this once, e.g. in `FormShow`:

```
getlocaleformatsettings(locale_system_default, MyFormatSettings);
```

finally, this should work:

```
sb.panels[2].Text := format('%5.2f', EventRate, MyFormatSettings);
```

Comment: If the OP wants to show the time necessary to process one list item, shouldn't it be something like: "SomeFloat := 0.001 * (difference / List.Items.Count);" instead? Of course 0 items need to be handled before...

Comment: Yes i do have to divide.
EventPerMinute := List.Items.Count / difference / 1000;

Some solutions:
sb.panels[2].Text := floattostr(eventperminute); // OK but not formatted
sb.panels[2].Text := floattostrF(EventPerMinute ,ffNumber,4,3); // always 0
sb.panels[2].Text := Format('%f',[eventperminute]); // always 0
sb.panels[2].Text := FormatFloat('#,##0',EventPerMinute); // always 0
---------------

This calculation is on a Timer event, triggered every 1000 ms.

Comment: if there are 10 list items in 5000 milliseconds, then 10 / 5000 / 1000 will yield 0.000002 - no wonder you get zero!  Even if you do as I suggest, 10 / (5000 / 1000) = 2 this is in events PER SECOND not per minute.  For per minute, you'd have to divide by 60000!

Comment: I've edited variable name and added a source comment line to reflect my previous comment

Comment: Ah .... my fault. You are correct, i should have divided by 60000. Now even ###.## is showing. Thanks for the MyFormatting class prop. hint.

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you use format function with [format strings](http://www.delphitutorials.de/format-strings-zeichenketten-formatieren.html)? Example:

```
sb.panels[2].Text := Format('%8.2f',[123.456]);
```

Other functions would be

```
function FormatFloat(const Format: string; Value: Extended): string; overload;
function FormatFloat(const Format: string; Value: Extended; const FormatSettings: TFormatSettings): string; overload;
```

Comment: I have already try all those solutions .. example:
sb.panels[2].Text := FormatFloat('#,##0',((List.Items.Count) /  difference) / 1000); 

Result is always 0. What about the overload version? You have an example using it?

Comment: Maybe in your locals the , means the 1k delimiter and you should use . instead.

Comment: Thank you for the info, appreciated. My problem is now resolved.

Comment: this answer creates alot of whitespaces at beginning of string if number is low...